# Limiting comment length in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following anchor tag which was originally written in Angular. I am converting it into react.

```
<a className="su__list-item-desc su__w-100 su__my-1 su__font-regular su__mb-2 font-14 su__loading-view" href={comment._source.url} target="_blank" bind-html-compile="comment.highlight['comment_nested.body'][0] | limitTo: 1000" onClick={() => props.linkOpened(props.result, index + 1)} style={{display: 'list-item', marginLeft: '0.3em', listStyleType: 'circle'}}>{ comment._source ? decodeHTML(comment._source.body) :'' }</a>
```

I want to restrict the length of the content inside the anchor tag. But, I am facing some problem to implement the same in react.

```
import React, { useState, createElement } from "react";

export default function CommentNest(props) {
  let [commentNested, setCommentNested] = useState(true);
  let comments = props.result.comment_nested;
  let commentCount = 3;
  let commentLength = props.result.comment_nested.length;
  let showNestedComments = false;
  let resultId = [];
  let tempIndex;

  const handleButtonClick = (commentNested) => {
    setCommentNested(!commentNested);
  };

  const handleCommentClick = () => {
    showAllComments(props.result.comment_nested.length, props.result._id);
    checkResultIdExist(props.result._id, props.result.comment_nested.length);
  };

  const decodeHTML = function (html) {
    let txt = createElement("textarea", null, html);
    return txt.value;
  };

  const showAllComments = function (length, id) {
    resultId.push(id);
    resultId = [...new Set(resultId)];
    if (commentCount <= 3 && id) {
      commentCount = length;
    } else {
      commentCount = 3;
      tempIndex = resultId.findIndex((el) => el == id);
      if (tempIndex >= 0) resultId.splice(tempIndex, 1);
    }
    showComments = !showComments;
  };

  const checkResultIdExist = function (id, length) {
    tempIndex = resultId.findIndex((el) => el == id);
    if (tempIndex >= 0) {
      showNestedComments = true;
    } else {
      showNestedComments = false;
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div
        className="su__position-relative su__border-t su__p-3 su__bg-gray-40 clearfix su__w-80 su__cursor su__text-semi-gray"
        className={`su__active-Filter-color ${commentNested ? "active" : ""}`}
      >
        <div className="font-14" onClick={handleButtonClick}>
          <span>Comments</span>
        </div>
        <div
          className="su__filter-group-row su__fadeInDownSmall"
          style={{ display: commentNested ? "block" : "none" }}
          className="su-filter-value-wrapper collapse in fade"
        >
          {comments.map(function (comment, index) {
            return (
              <>
                {index + 1 <= commentCount && (
                  <div
                    key={Math.random().toString(10)}
                    className="su__list-elem-tag su__loading-view custom_comments nested_comments"
                    style={{
                      overflow: "hidden",
                      whiteSpace: "nowrap",
                      textOverflow: "ellipsis",
                      padding: "5px 9px",
                    }}
                  >
                    <a
                      className="su__list-item-desc su__w-100 su__my-1 su__font-regular su__mb-2 font-14 su__loading-view"
                      href={comment._source.url}
                      target="_blank"
                      bind-html-compile="comment.highlight['comment_nested.body'][0] | limitTo: 1000"
                      onClick={() => props.linkOpened(props.result, index + 1)}
                      style={{
                        display: "list-item",
                        marginLeft: "0.3em",
                        listStyleType: "circle",
                      }}
                    >
                      {comment._source ? decodeHTML(comment._source.body) : ""}
                    </a>
                  </div>
                )}
              </>
            );
          })}
        </div>
        {commentLength > 3 && (
          <div onClick={handleCommentClick}>
            <span>{showNestedComments ? "Show less" : "Show more"}</span>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

I tried creating replacing the bind-html-compile with dangerouslySetInnerHTML. But, I am confused in how to implement the "comment.highlight['comment_nested.body'][0] | limitTo: 1000" as in the above code in react.

Comment: What have you tried in React? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example Are you referring specifically to the `comment._source ? decodeHTML(comment._source.body) : ''` content?

Comment: I tried replacing the bind-html-compile with dangerouslySetInnerHTML and using the substring on the decodeHTML(comment._source.body) but didn't get the desired output.

Comment: Please do update your question to include your attempt. We can't help debug code we can't see.

Comment: I am sorry, I have added the entire code of the file. I only have a little idea about dangerouslySetInnerHTML. But, don't know how to implement the above functionality in react.

Comment: No worries. Can you also share what this `comment._source.body` value is that you are wanting to render? Can you please also clarify more precisely what is meant by "limiting the comment length"? What does `"comment.highlight['comment_nested.body'][0] | limitTo: 1000"` in Angular do? Are you just wanting to limit the number of characters displayed?

Comment: comment._source.body is being received from the props. I want to render the output returned by the decodeHTML(comment._source.body) function. Yes, I want to limit the comment._source.body. It can considered as a comment body with character limit to 1000. comment.highlight['comment_nested.body'][0] | limitTo: 1000 is basically finding if comment.highlight['comment_nested.body'][0]  is there and if it is present, the character limit of the comment body wil be set to 1000 characters in length.

Comment: Is `comment._source.body` plain text? Or is it HTML that needs to be rendered/escaped? Can you share an example value?

Comment: It is a html value. It basically contains the html code of the comment body. Comments are coming via the props.

Comment: Yes, comment._source.body needs to be rendered. I want to set the character length of this one only.